# Windows ACL and the ACCESS_MASK

Tags: c++, winapi, acl, windows-7-x64

In a C++ program, I'm trying to get a file to be writable and deleteable by a different account than the one that created the file. To do this, I have found I have to dig in to ACLs.

My question is really about the [`ACCESS_MASK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374892.aspx).

I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down what it means by:

- "Specific rights"
- "Standard rights"
- "Generic"

Setting the Generic bits seems to show up as a change to "Everyone" when I look at the properties of the file. Is that what I should be expecting? What are the other two?

(BTW, this answer was VERY helpful in getting things working: [How to give "Everyone" write permissions via C++ MFC on Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096772/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific rights are those tied to the particular type of object, such as file, thread, process, event, etc. Standard rights are common to all objects (at least where the right makes sense), while generic rights are whatever makes sense for the object type. For example, for [file access rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364399), `GENERIC_READ` gets mapped to `FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES | STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | SYNCHRONIZE`, where `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ` is defined as `READ_CONTROL`.

Comment: Okay. I think I am catching up. The line "ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-1-0", &psid);" gives me the "Everyone" sid. I then apply "GENERIC_ALL" and I have read, write, and everything else on the "Everyone" user. So it wasn't the "Generic" that set "Everyone", it was the SID I requested.
Thanks!

Comment: @SimonParker, FYI, `ConvertStringSidToSid` supports SID aliases (defined in sddl.h), which may be easier to remember. "Everyone" is sometimes called "World", so the alias is "WD". Some other common ones are "CO" (Creator Owner), "OW" (Owner Rights), "AU" (Authenticated Users), "AN" (Anonymous Logon), "SY" (Local System), "LS" (Local Service), "NS" (Network Service), "LA" (Local Administrator), "LG" (Local Guest), "BA" (Builtin Administrators), "BU" (Builtin Users), and "BG" (Builtin Guests). icacls.exe also supports aliases if prefixed with "*", e.g. `icacls filename /grant *BA:F`.